# Angular - Making String Safe for URL - Is Route this correct?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To make my app SEO friendly/easier for users to read URLs I'm appending the title of page clicked on to each URL.

So for example if a user clicks on the story 'Asia Stocks Climb' they are sent to the url:

```
mysite.com/story/34324/asia-stocks-climb
```

In my routes.js I specify that a URL containing some text at the end will exist but essentially i ignore it:

```
.when("/story/:id/:pageTitle",
    {
      templateUrl: "views/story.html",
      controller: 'Story' ,
      controllerAs: 'story'
    }
  )
```

So my questions:

1 - Is this OK to do (for SEO) append that to the end of URLs only when they are clicked?

2 - To get that text story 'Asia Stocks Climb' to become URL friendly 'asia-stocks-url' I'm using my own code:

```
textContent.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-').replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'')
```

I've tested and it seems ok however is there an Angular method for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's 100% correct, I use this:

```
$scope.slugify = function (Text) {
  if (Text == null || Text == 'undefined')
     return "";

  return Text
       .toLowerCase()
       .replace(/[^\w ]+/g, '')
       .replace(/ +/g, '-');
}
```